# ROKU: Associative Array with multiple values

Tags: arrays, roku, brightscript

I have a 2 part question that I am hoping someone can help me with.

I am trying to figure out how to pass an array of years from my server to my ROKU code. It is going to be a variable number of years, meaning there won't always be the same number of elements in the array.

What I need to figure out is how to set up the array, and then how to parse it in `BrightScript`.

Here is an example of what I have so far. I have the count, but still need to add all the years.

The list of years is `1998,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014`

```
{
"Items" : [
  {
    "name": "count",
    "value": "13"
  }
]}
```

Once it's received in my ROKU code, I will need to loop over the years, and display them, one per line.  (I already have the display part done. I just need help knowing how to get at the array elements.)

Since there is so little useful documentation out there for `BrightScript` arrays, I'm hoping someone with more experience will be able to answer this, and that it will help someone else in the future.

Comment: Have you tried using ParseJSON on the Roku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do any of that. Just send the JSON array and Roku will parse it:

```
BrightScript Debugger> myJSON = "[1998,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014]" 
BrightScript Debugger> ? type(myJSON)
String

BrightScript Debugger> arr = parseJSON(myJSON)
BrightScript Debugger> ? type(arr)
roArray
```

It's perfectly valid to have array as top-level element of the json text ("A JSON text is a serialized object or array." per [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)). You can also do it with a dummy object (but why?):
`arr = parseJSON(" {"years": [1998, 2003]} ").years`

Comment: Thank you. I knew there had to be an easier way. I just needed someone to show me. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it:

Array:

```
{ 
 "Items" : [ 
     { "value": "2014" } , 
     { "value": "2013" } , 
     { "value": "2012" } , 
     { "value": "2011" } , 
     { "value": "2010" } , 
     { "value": "2009" } , 
     { "value": "2008" } , 
     { "value": "2007" } , 
     { "value": "2006" } , 
     { "value": "2005" } , 
     { "value": "2004" } , 
     { "value": "2003" } , 
     { "value": "1998" } 
   ]
}
```

BrightScript code to parse it:

```
    arr = CreateObject("roArray",json.Items.count(),false)

    for each item in json.Items
       thisItem = {
        value: item.value         
       }
       arr.push(thisItem)
    end for
    return arr
```

I hope this helps someone else in the future.